# how to "push()" data to a existing array in firebase using vuejs?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i would like to add the 'events' id in the current user collection in my database, i achieve to get and push the Id of the user to the events collection but i don't achieve to puts multiple events Id in the user collection.
I would like to know how to push events id to the user collection, each time the user create a new event, the event is pushed in an array ?
My code look like that :

```
async createEvent() {
        await db
          .collection("events")
          .add({
            //some stuff
          })
          .then(function (docRef) {
            let lastID = docRef.id;
            let authRes = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            db.collection("users")
              .doc(authRes.uid)
              .update({ event: lastID }); //the problem is there, i would like to push the
                                            last event Id and update the user collection
          });
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a handy method called `FieldValue.arrayUnion`, which will take your value, and add it to an array if the value does not exist.

You can use it like this:

```
db.collection("users")
              .doc(authRes.uid)
              .set({ event: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(lastID) }, {merge: true});
```

Note that if you do this, `event` will be an array of strings like this:

```
['eventId1', 'eventId2', 'eventId3']
```